# Opening Project from TFS Dashboard causes Visual Studio Web Handler Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm trying to open a project from TFS 2018 (on-premises installation but I guess that would happen with any version or VSTS as well) dashboard but I can't.

I click on url Open in Visual Studio:
[image]

And an error form shows up:
[image]

The error description says:

```
Input args:/openurivsweb://vs/Product=Visual_Studio&EncFormat=UTF8&tfslink=dnN0ZnM6Ly8vRnJhbWV3b3JrL1RlYW1Qcm9qZWN0L2I1MjI0OWRjLTdhMDUtNDI1Yi1iZTE5LWNmMDM5YzE1YTJlND91cmw9aHR0cHM6Ly90ZnMubWFucG93ZXIuaXQvTmV4dEcv
Exception thrown:'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWebHandler.VSWebHandlerException'.
```

I have installed both VS2012 and 2017.

I tried also this workaround, but with no success:

```
Launch Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 as Administrator
Go to VS 2017 installation folder, for example: pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
Launch command: gacutil -if Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll
```

Comment: Based on the icon, it looks like Visual Studio 2012 is trying to handle the request. Have you looked at the Windows Default App Settings to make sure the 2017 handler is registered as the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows Default Apps panel open the protocol handlers and scroll down to the `vsweb:` and the `vstfs:` protocol handlers. It could have multiple instances of the handler, one of which has to have the 2017 icon. Mine is showing 2 2017 icons because I have the 2017 preview installed side by side.

[image]

Change the default, restart the browser and try again.

Comment: Thx buddy!
just I forgot that was on Windows 7 machine but I'm gonna add these infos

Comment: Process is the same, the screen looks different though.

Comment: Yup, that's why I added it :) might be useful for sbody

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jessehouwing answer, that works for Windows Metro UI systems (8 and superiors), this is what you need for Windows 7.

Go to Control Panel, select Default Programs and click the second option:
[image]

Then it opens the window where you have to change the association between Visual Studio Web Handler Selector and TFS Procotol Handler (*vstfs:*):

[image]

From the icon, as suggested, you can see that's Visual Studio 2012 symbol.
Now we change it:

[image]

Sorry bout Italian language, but procedure would be the same with any localization.